# Create .csv file through a Control file

Tags: csv, sql-loader

I have to create some csv files through a sql loader control file reference. I have written this code:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '$ROOT_FOLDER/xxx/xxx/xxx/example.csv' "str '\n'"
discardfile '$ROOT_FOLDER/xxx/xxx/xxx/example.dsc'
Append

INTO TABLE TABLE1
when (9) = ','
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
  Field1                       CHAR  "to_date(:Field1,'YYYYMMDD')"
  ,Field2                      CHAR
  ,Field3                      FILLER char
  ,Field4                      FILLER char
  ,Field5                      CHAR
)
```

When I run the code three csv files are created, two are correct and the last one not.

This is the example of one correct csv:

```
INT_PROCESS,18.10.2019 05:35:02,18.10.2019 05:35:02,9
Date,Instrument ID,Instrument ID Type,Exchange Code,Close
20191017,XXXX=,F1,F2, -.49900
,GBP3MFSR=,F1,F2,
20191017,AAAA=,F1,F2,2.00000
20191016,BBBB=,F1,F2,1.90000
20191017,CCCC=,F1,F2, -.44800
20191017,DDDD=,F1,F2, -.41000
20191016,EEEE=,F1,F2,.71090
,FFFF=,F1,F2,
,GGGG=,F1,F2,
```

and this what I have into the wrong one:

```
Date,Instrument ID,Instrument ID Type,Exchange Code,Close
20191016,XXXX=,F1,F3, -.551
20191016,YYYY=,F1,F2, -.466
```

How can I fix my code in such a way that I have three csv with the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you don't want any files but the `.log` file created. See the `.log` file for details on the errors, but `sqlldr` attempts to load the data in the INFILE clause into the table specified.  Output will be a `.log` file, a `.bad` file for records that caused errors and a discard file that contains records that did not meet your condition criteria.  Your goal should be to load without creating a .bad or .dsc file.

Also I think your Field1 entry is wrong as you normally don't insert a DATE datatype into a CHAR column.

You may need to do some reading before continuing:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-34A050B6-3FD7-4B77-97D2-04C03D359D16